# Cуществуют ли исследования тонической системы русского языка?

Tags: синтаксис

Известно, что в русском языке интонация (тон) важна для смысла высказывания, и что тональность играет синтаксическую роль (вопросительная, восклицательная, модальное значение интонации и т.д.)

Существуют ли исследования по тональности русского языка? Есть ли шкала синтаксических тонов?

Answer (score 2):

Конечно же существуют, их много, например [вот](http://rusgram.narod.ru/136-154.html) (с §150 по §171). Или [вот](http://fonetica.philol.msu.ru/index1.htm).